# Spark hbase input format example error

Tags: python, hbase, apache-spark

I try to load an hbase table into a spark rdd in python and i fail.
I created a test table as in the comments of the example code.
I use spark 1.2.1 and hadoop 2.5.1

When I launch this:

```
spark2/bin/spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 --driver-class-path spark2/lib/spark-examples-1.2.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar spark2/examples/src/main/python/hbase_inputformat.py master test
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/spark2/examples/src/main/python/hbase_inputformat.py", line 74, in <module>
    conf=conf)
  File "/home/user/spark2/python/pyspark/context.py", line 530, in newAPIHadoopRDD
    jconf, batchSize)
  File "/home/user/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/home/user/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
        at org.apache.spark.mapreduce.SparkHadoopMapReduceUtil$class.firstAvailableClass(SparkHadoopMapReduceUtil.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.mapreduce.SparkHadoopMapReduceUtil$class.newJobContext(SparkHadoopMapReduceUtil.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.newJobContext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:203)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.getPartitions(MappedRDD.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:203)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1060)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1093)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$.pairRDDToPython(SerDeUtil.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala:500)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Some class miss-match or class implementation not implement

Comment: did you ever find the solution?  I am having the same problem.

Comment: The same issue here. Still no solution? I have been searching for pyspark-hbase working case for months, but still no luck.

Comment: My workaround is to use an hbase api inside the map function and make the connection there. I worked with partitions to reduce the connections.

Comment: Here is a working example for pyspark-hbase http://cjcroix.blogspot.in/2015/10/pyspark-hbase-and-spark-streaming-save.html